# Unknown modifier 'l' error

Tags: php, regex

```
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'l' in /var/www/test.php on line 9
```

It's saying my regex has an unknown modifier, but I'm not sure what exactly is happening to trigger the error

```
preg_match_all("/\<select id\=\'subscription_division_id\'(.+?)</select>\/is", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are escaping wrong. For the regex parser, the following is your regex:

```
\<select id\=\'subscription_division_id\'(.+?)<
```

whereas `select>\/is` is supposed to be the regexp modifiers (the regex string is enclosed in `/`). Given that the `l` in there is the first invalid modifier, you receive that error. So to fix that, you need to escape the slash in the closing tag. And btw. you are escaping quite a lot unnecessary things, this is enough:

```
preg_match_all("/<select id='subscription_division_id'(.+?)<\/select>/is", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: +1 Using a different delimiter (typically `~`) would be even better, so no escaping is required at all.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP’s PCRE functions](http://php.net/pcre) require the pattern to be delimited by [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) that separate the pattern from optional [modifiers](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers). But these delimiters need to be escaped if they occur inside the pattern. So you need to escape the delimiters `/` inside your pattern:

```
"/\<select id\=\'subscription_division_id\'(.+?)<\/select>/is"
                                                  ^
```

Otherwise the pattern is ended prematurely and the rest is interpreted as modifiers. Like in your case where the rest (i.e. `select>/is`) is interpreted as such. *s* and *e* are valid modifiers but *l* isn’t. That’s the reason for your error message.